# NoReverseMatch for Django form

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am running into the NoReverseMatch error.  Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Exception value: Reverse for 'profile_list.html' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

edit_profile.html

```
<h1>Add Profile</h1>

<form action="{% url 'questions-new' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <ul>
    {{ form.as_ul }}
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<a href="{% url 'profile-list' %}">back to list</a>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

import questions.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', questions.views.ListProfileView.as_view(),
        name='profile-list'),
    url(r'^new$', questions.views.CreateProfileView.as_view(),
        name='questions-new',),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

from questions.models import Profile

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class ListProfileView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profile_list.html'

class CreateProfileView(CreateView):

    model = Profile
    template_name = 'edit_profile.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_list.html')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `get_success_url` is wrong. Change it to the following:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('profile-list')
```

`reverse` should be used in conjunction with the names that you give inside your `urls.py` patterns and not template names.

Answer (score 2):

Your `reverse` call is incorrect. According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse):

> reverse(viewname[, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None,
>   current_app=None])
>
> viewname is either the function name (either a
>   function reference, or the string version of the name, if you used
>   that form in urlpatterns) or the URL pattern name.

So, replace

```
reverse('profile_list.html')
```

with

```
reverse('profile-list')
```

`profile-list` is the URL pattern name, that you've defined in `urls.py`.

Hope that helps.